# Почему программа независимо от истинности условия if (maxMod5 % 5 == 0) выводит else? C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i, maxMod5, a[3];
    std::cout << "Введите через пробел 4 числа: " << std::endl;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            std::cin >> a[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] >= maxMod5)
            {
                maxMod5 = a[i];
            }
        }
    if(maxMod5 % 5 == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Максимальное число кратное 5: " << maxMod5 << std::endl;
    }else 
    {
        std::cout << "Вы не ввели ни одного числа, которое кратно 5 "
        << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `maxMod5` used uninitialized, `a` addressed past its end, да тут просто фестиваль UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int ... a[4];
    ...
    maxMod5 = a[0]; // !!!
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] >= maxMod5)
        {
            maxMod5 = a[i];
        }
    }
```

---

Вы что хотите найти? Сообщения противоречат коду.

Comment: @manvelias Неинициализированная переменная `maxMod5` содержит мусор, который обычно соответствует какому-нибудь очень большому числу некратному пяти.

Comment: Понял, респект за объяснение, вопрос свой исправил!)